# Insert code in to field or center of content type that already has 1000's of nodes

Tags: nodes

So i'm trying to put Google Adsense in to the middle of a node of a few different content types and have tried does this in various ways but to no avail.

The latest method was to put the google adsense in to a block, which works and then use block reference module as a field, this bit works too which in turn shows the google adsense in the exact place I want it, above certain fields and next to the main body field. The problem with this method is that I want it to show on every node already created, which there are thousands of. I have used https://www.drupal.org/project/field_defaults to select the block on that field and to force it to show on all already created nodes, but this last bit doesn't work. I still have to go through the nodes individually and add the block reference.

Another method I tried was to create a field called Google Ad Content and then add the default google adsense code, as above, this doesn't work because I have to preselect the text format to work with the google adsense code and also update all of the nodes and I end up with the same problem as above.

How else can I go about this?

Comment: I hope this can be done through themeing the content type

Comment: It can also be done via contrib modules. With Display Suite, for instance, you can place a block as a field. Similar with Panels etc. The most lightweight method would be through the node template and preprocess function for the node, ie. the theming layer. https://www.drupal.org/node/223430 and https://www.drupal.org/node/345361 to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/eba inserts a block in to the manage display area of each node or entity, this has allowed me to add a google ad in the middle of the content between any fields I want on any entity I want and to 1000s of already published nodes.